# CakePHP shell cronjobs stopped working after changing passwords

Tags: php, mysql, shell, cakephp, cron

We're doing some server maintenance for a client of ours. One of the tasks was to change all server passwords (user account + mysql accounts). I ended up changing the passwords for all SSH accounts which were enabled and changing the password for the MySQL root and user for the website database.

The client is running a website developed on CakePHP 2.3.6. After changing the database passwords, I edited the config (/app/config/database.php). All works well, expect for one thing: the shell cronjobs has stopped working. Under the user account www-data there are three cronjobs:

```
20 3   *   *   *   /var/www/sitename/app/Console/cake parse >> /var/log/cakephp_cron/parse.log
30 3   *   *   *   /var/www/sitename/app/Console/cake get_feed >> /var/log/cakephp_cron/get_feed.log
40 3   *   *   *   /var/www/sitename/app/Console/cake maintenance >> /var/log/cakephp_cron/maintenance.log
```

The cronjobs take care of updating some affiliate feeds. I check the log files (parse.log, get_feed.log and maintenance.log) and they are getting updated, so the cronjob is still running. However, the feed is not getting updated anymore since changing the passwords. The log's don't throw any error messages at all and are, for that regard, useless.

As I'm not a CakePHP expert, and the documentation on the website of CakePHP won't tell me a great deal about the configuration for cronjobs, I'm hoping that someone here knows what is going wrong. Are there any more configuration file's with the database credentials that I need to edit? Is there a configuration file for the shell cronjobs that should be edited?  In other words: any idea what is going wrong and where should I get started searching for the solution?

Answer (score 0):

basically these are custom scripts that aren't part of the CakePHP platform. You'll need to find the code for them and my guess is they have some variables that are being used for the password.

The normal file location is `/app/Console/Command/`. You might see `ParseShell.php`. If so, take a look in that file and it will have the code for this particular cron job. The passwords may be hard coded but they could also use the `Configure` system to load in a variable: `Configure::read('parse.api.password.example');` You can then search for that string in the project and find where the variable is set and update it (probably in `/app/Config` somewhere)